# Add worksheet in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Receiving an error in the following code.  The For-Next section works, but throws an error on the wb2.sheets.add line.  Runtime Error 424 Object required.

This used to work, not sure what changed. Is there a syntax error?

```
'Look for existing sheets named "For Export
'If found, delete existing sheet
For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If S.Name = "For Export" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ' Workbook.Worksheets.Item(S.Name).Delete
    End If
Next S

'Add sheet named "For Export"

Set wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
wb2.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = "For Export"
```

Comment: wb was assigned.  I just noticed worksheets.delete line was commented out, which was throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

'Look for existing sheets named "For Export
'If found, delete existing sheet
For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

```
If S.Name = "For Export" Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Workbook.Worksheets.Item(S.Name).Delete
End If
Next S

'Add sheet named "For Export"

Set wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
wb2.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = "For Export"
```

In the original code, the workbook.delete line was commented out, which threw an error when trying to add a sheet by the same name.